# Altering value of a record in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state, records

I'm pretty new to Haskell and to practice, I've decided to make a d&d style game where the battles are based on dice rolls, and whoever has the bigger number wins. However, I'm a bit confused on how to change the value of my records and change the global value of the record.

Here is my record code:

```
data PlayerStats = PlayerStats { health :: Health
                              ,mana :: Mana
                              ,inventory :: [Items]   }deriving (Show,Eq)




defaultStats = PlayerStats {health = 100, mana = 50, inventory = []}
```

And here is my function to take damage if the player loses the dice roll:

```
takeDamage:: State PlayerStats ()
takeDamage = do
         let h = defaultStats health 
         h <- get
         put $ (h - 10)
```

I've looked all over the internet for a solution to a problem like mine, but haven't found anything, so I think this could be useful to other people in my situation.

Comment: When you say `State` is this from `Control.Monad.Trans.State` from the transformers library or a different module?

Comment: I'm using Control.Monad.State

Answer (score 4):

First, `defaultStats :: PlayerStats`, which is a record, not a function, so:

```
defaultStats health
```

doesn't make sense.  On the other hand, `health :: PlayerStats -> Health` is a function, so

```
health defaultStats
```

makes more sense, but is essentially the constant `100`, since that is the `health` of a `defaultStats`.  However, in this case, it doesn't make sense, since you immediately introduce a new `h`, bound to `get`, which (assuming `State` is `Control.Monad.Trans.State`), gets the current `PlayerStats` from the `State` `Monad`.  Note that `h` will be the whole `PlayerStats`, not just the `health` component.

Record update really creates a new record from an existing one with one or more fields replaced with new values.  In this case, you wish to replace the `health` field with the current value minus `10`:

```
takeDamage = do
  ps <- get
  put $ ps { health = health ps - 10 }
```

Here, we get the current `PlayerStats` from the `State` `Monad` as `ps`, and then `put` a new `PlayerStats` based on the current one, but with the `health` field set to the current `health` minus `10`.  In the record update syntax, the `health` on the left of the `=` refers to the field name, and the `health` on the right refers to the accessor function that gets the `health` field from an existing record.

The `get` followed by `put` is common enough that there's a `modify` function that takes a function that transforms the state, and wraps it with the `get` and `put`:

```
takeDamage = modify $ \ps -> ps { health = health ps - 10 }
```

Record update syntax is a huge Haskell wart.  You might want to check out [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), which make updating fields in a `State` `Monad` very easy (although the error messages you get when you mess up will make your brain melt).

**Edit**

If you want to see if your player lost all health, you can have the `takeDamage` function return a `Bool` indicating if the player survived:

```
takeDamage :: State PlayerStats Bool
takeDamage = do
  ps <- get
  let health' = health ps - 10
  put $ ps { health = health' } -- update health even if dead!
  return (health' > 0)

playRound :: State PlayerStats ()
playRound = do
  survived <- takeDamage
  if survived
    then do
      ...
    else do
      ...
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. The record syntax was really confusing to me, since I've only ever seriously coded in C#, Python, and JavaScript. So, if I wanted to evaluate the value later on (to see if the player is dead), how would that syntax look in an if, then, else context?